# How to render a partial in a foreach asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2

I have two partial view and I want to call one of them in another . it works in this condition but when I put in foreach it shows error .

@{
    Layout = null;
    }

```
<div class="comment">
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
<div class="co10">
<div class="co12 , text1">@Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => item.Date)</div>
<div class="co11 , text5">@Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => item.NameFamily)<font class="text1"> در </font><font class="text6">@Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => item.Topic.Title)</font></div>
</div>
<div class="co13 , text1">
<div class="co14">@Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => item.CommentMessage)</div>
<div class="but4 , text15"><a href="#1">پاسخ</a></div>
</div>
<div class="co15"></div>
@{Html.RenderAction("_RespondedComment", "SharedEdu", new { Q4 = item.ID });}
}

</div>
```

When I put _RespondedComment in foreach loop it shows error but when I put it out of foreach it works but I want to show response comment for each comment .

how can I do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're directly in the body of the `foreach`.
That is a code context, so you can't write `@{ ... }` to put in more code.

Instead, put in the code directly.

Comment: :)) .. Thank you . A very bad mistake :D .